# What the EMR Advantage patient portal lets patients see, and what it doesn't let them see

Tags: website

I used to live in Ottawa.  At the time, I visited an Appletree Medical Group doctor.  The doctor then stored some information in my electronic medical record ("chart").

This week, my dental-hygiene clinic asked me for some information from my chart.

Today, I logged into the [Appletree patient portal](https://www.appletreepatients.com/), which is really just an instance of the Canadian Health Systems EMR Advantage patient portal.  But I couldn't find the information I was looking for.

Why not?

Comment: I couldn't find any really good pre-existing tags for this post. If you wish, perhaps you could create some tags such as: health emr medical-records emr-advantage canada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I phoned up Canadian Health Systems.

They explained that the EMR Advantage patient portal doesn't let you view your entire chart.  It only lets you view certain pieces of information, such as your lab test results.